# how to Color part of text of a output to a console

Tags: linux, console

Is there a way to color particular words printed on console based on user preference?

For example I need to color text 'error' when a particular program is compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to work with the output and some script/alias. Check [So You Like Colors](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8603) for reference of how to use colors in terminal.
Example:

```
gcc main.c 2>&1 | sed -e 's/\(error\)/^[[1;31m\1^[[m/'
```

BEWARE: the first `^[` above is a escape sequence, press Ctrl-V + ESC to create them.
I'm redirection `2>&1` *stderr* to *stdout* and replacing `sed` error with error in bold and red color. And finally reseting colors and attributes back to normal `^[[m`.

Result in that: [image: example of coloring just error]
You should setup some script/alias in your *~/.bashrc*.

Comment: Use `tput` instead of hardcoding the sequences.

Comment: `tput` is owned by ncurses here, if you don't care about one more dependence use `tput`.

Comment: Thank you, I found this also useful - http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/511

Answer (score 1):

That case has probably been already done, see the [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) script.